# Webpage does not refresh on date selection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, power-automate

I am trying to implement basic automation using Power Automate Desktop to change date selection on webpage and download the report. To do this I am injecting following javascript, which does change the date for me but webpage does not get updated as it should be updated once new date is selected. I have attached the link for snap  where I manually select the date and webpage updates.
Can anyone help me to achieve this task of updating webpage when new date is selected.

P.s: I am not familiar with Javascript, the code I am using was taken from someone else.

```
document.getElementById("accPanelFilter:formFilter:panelSearch:j_idt80:j_idt82:daySelectGasDay:daySelectGasDaycalendar:daySelectGasDaycalendarcalendar_input").value = "10-11-2021";
```

[image]

Comment: The effect of "refreshing the page" is driven by an _event_, not simply by changing the value of the input element. You'll have to synthetically trigger the correct event for that to work. We would have no idea what event that would be.

Comment: How can I synthetically trigger correct event? is there any code for that?

Comment: Repeating:: "_We would have no idea what event that would be_" - do you know what event it is that causes the refresh? That's your challenge - find that out.

Comment: I think I have not explained very well my problem. Everytime